# When I try to deploy my function in firebase, it shows me "Error: Functions did not deploy properly". How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send message through firebase cloud message via firebase cloud function. Here's my code below

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const axios = require('axios');
//import axios from 'axios';

exports.abc = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 50 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {

let response=await axios.get(
    'https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/bangladesh'
);
console.log(response.data);
let body=response.data.todayDeaths;
console.log(body);


let message = {
    notification: {
        'title': 'Today death',
        'body': `${body}`,
    },
    topic:'allUser'
    
};


admin.messaging().send(message)
.then(response=>{
    console.log("Successfully sent",response);
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log("failed",response);
});


console.log('This will be run every 2 minutes!');
return null;
});
```

But when I tried to deploy my function, I am getting an error

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    abc(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
firebase deploy --only "functions:abc"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

And this the error notification from log of firebase cloud function

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'axios'
Require stack:
```

and also

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. 
Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Function cannot be 
initialized.


{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the 
user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional 
troubleshooting documentation can be found at 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting 
documentation."},"authenticationInfo":
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Did you run `npm install axios` in your functions directory?

Comment: yes.I did. But don't know why it shows me "Cannot find module 'axios'"

Comment: I think you need to update your whole functions folder server side. Go to your functions dashboard and delete `abc` if it's there. Then run `firebase deploy --only functions` that'll redeploy all your functions and update the `package.json` that your function container has

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?